# jQuery to output data value of two checkbox comma separated on another checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

Suppose I have two checkbox like these (can be 100 checkboxes as it will be coming in a while loop)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="20" data="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" value="30" data="Mango">
```

And I have two textboxes where I want to output values 20+30 = 50 and Apple, Mango.

```
<input type="text" id="value1"> // to output sum of values i.e., 50 
<input type="text" id="value2"> // to output comma separated data values Apple, Mango on select
```

Here I am able to do the first operation. But I am not sure how to do the second one. what I want is when I check the boxes its sums values and outputs it on 1st text box and when unchecks any box it deducts the values back (its already working as I was able to do it) and the second box should output values Apple, Mango when both boxes are checked respectively. If any box is unchecked say box with data value Mango then the textbox value will become Apple (even comma gets removed) only. How to do this? Here is my currennt jQuery code below for completing the 1st operation. How to do the second one? What else should I add here in this code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#costdisplay").html(total);
    $("input[name=amount]").val(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: Get the contents of the `data` attributes (which should really rather be named `data-something`, because that is the correct syntax for custom data attributes) inside your loop and put them into an array ... and then simply `join` that array afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var txt = '';
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
      txt += $(this).attr('data')+', ';
    });
    $("#costdisplay").html(total);
    $("input[name=amount]").val(total);
    $("#value2").val(txt.slice(0,-2));
  });
});
```

Comment: working perfect.. one last thing.. need one space before the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... words.. means currently its `Value1,Value2,Value3` and needed `Value1, Value2, Value3`..can be done?

Comment: just add space after comma txt += $(this).attr('data')+', ';  and add -2 insted of -1 $("#value2").val(txt.slice(0,-2));

Comment: slice(0,-2) is ommitting the last letter from the word if there is only one value selected..

Comment: Yeah.. heavenly perfect.. accepting it.. thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if below code works for you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    var dataval = "";
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      total += isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? 0 : parseInt(val);
      dataval += $(this).attr('data') +", ";
    });
    $("#value1").val(total);
    $("#value2").val(dataval.slice(0,-2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="checkbox" value="20" data="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" value="30" data="Mango">


<input type="text" id="value1"> // to output sum of values i.e., 50 
<input type="text" id="value2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store arbitrary data, which can be fetched using [`$.fn.data(key)`.](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var $elem = $('input:checkbox:checked'),
      $amount = $("input[name=amount]"),
      $costdisplay = $("#costdisplay"),
      dataValues = [],
      total = 0;
      
    if ($elem.length) {
      
      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
        dataValues.push($(this).data('value')); //Iterate and populate the array from custom attribute
      });

    }
    
    $amount.val(total);
    $costdisplay.val(dataValues.join(','));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="20" data-value="Apple">Apple<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="30" data-value="Mango">Mango<br/>

<input type="text" name="amount"> <br/>
<input type="text" id="costdisplay"> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

While calculating the total amount also make string having the data value with comma separator.

Use the below code snippet for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   var total = 0;
   var data = '';
   $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
      if(data) {
          data += ','+ $(this).attr('data');
      } else {
          data += $(this).attr('data');
      }
   });
   $("#costdisplay").html(total);
   $("input[name=amount]").val(total);
   $("#value2").val(data);
 });
});
```